# I have a problem with the Flutter i need to skip the a error without updating intl or flutter_localizations

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a problem with the Flutter i need to skip an error without updating  intl

> Running "flutter pub get" in fltox...
>   Because every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on
>   intl 0.16.0 and fstore depends on intl 0.15.8, flutter_localizations
>   from sdk is forbidden.

```
dependencies:
  logs:
    git: https://github.com/pq/logs
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: 0.15.8
  path: 1.6.4

more info 
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.12.13+hotfix.6, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.6 at /home/ppain/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 18cd7a3601 (5 weeks ago), 2019-12-11 06:35:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0.
```

ples help :)

Comment: What do you mean "skip an error"? If the current versions of the packages are incompatible, you will have to find versions that are compatible. Otherwise your build will not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem here is that `fstore` library depends on `intl: v0.16.0` but you have specifically defined any version above `v0.15.8`.

Which is causing this error.

To resolve this you can do the following:

1. You can update the `intl` library to `v0.16.0`
2. You can downgrade the `fstore` library to the version which supports `v0.15.8`

**I would suggest the second approach only if you have some specific dependency in your app which requires `intl:v0.15.8` and no other.**

However if your code requires some specific library version, I would suggest to make it more flexible to work with any version, otherwise in future you'll not be able to use some very useful new features of the library because of this.

Answer (score -1):

so i fix it by use

```
flutter version .
```

this command will show a list of flutter version 
by use

```
flutter version xxx
```

ex:

```
$ flutter version v1.7.8
```

will download this flutter version v1.7.8 or what you need .